# Jhipster gateway project make ng-bind-html work

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I am doing a micro service gateway. One of my entity has a field(its name is productImgHyperLink) which is a String field and has full html element like below will  be stored as its content.

```
<img src="http://image.xyz.com/images/I/431156.789.jpg" border="0" alt="Product Image">
```

In the generated .html, it can be show the content

```
<td>{{productInfo.productImgHyperLink}}</td>
```

However, I want to show it as an image, other than a text string.

I have tried

1. add 'ngSanitize', to the webapp\app.module.js
2. add a trustAshtml.js under weapp\app\compoments]util\
   the trustAshtml.js contnet is like below.

   ```
   /**
    * 
    */
   (function() {
       'use strict';

       angular
           .module('kdiStoreApp')
           .filter('trustAsHtml', trustAsHtml);

       function trustAsHtml($sce) {
           return function(html) {
               return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
           }
       }
   })();
   ```
3. Then changed the html of the field in the detail page to below.

   ```
   <td ng-bind-html={{productInfo.productImgHyperLink | trustAsHtml}}></td>
   ```

However, it can not show the image on the output.

4. the output on final html is something like below:

   ```
   <td ng-bind-html="<img src="http://image.xyz.com/images/I/431156.789.jpg" border="0" alt="Product Image">"></td>
   ```
5. the output,  it is the same as  using below without "  | trustAsHtml"

   ```
   <td ng-bind-html={{productInfo.productImgHyperLink}}></td>
   ```

Please anyone have any suggestion on how to make the image showing up? Thanks.

Comment: The correct syntax is `{{ productInfo.productImgHyperLink  | trustAsHtml }}`

Comment: Thanks, that was a type wrong. In  {{ productInfo.productImgHyperLink | trustAsHtml }}, it is not showing up, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to be displayed you should use `<img ng-src={{your-link-property}}></img>`. Sorry didn't see you are saving a complete html tag.